# PowerShell: Return $PSItem/$_ Looked up Within a ForEach-Object Script Block

Tags: powershell

I've been working on this problem in my personal time for days now...

I need to add a column to the results (Example issue. The code below will eventually error out. [I was just using -Include to test on a single row. My real-world problem uses a different cmdlet, but the same premise).

How do I get what the query was ran for to show up in the resulting table?

```
 ForEach-Object {Get-Service $_.name -DependentServices}
```

What I need it to look like.

| Status | Name | DisplayName | Parent Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stopped | workfolderssvc | Work Folders | WSearch |
| Stopped | WMPNetworkSvc | Windows Media Player Network Sharin... | WSearch |
| Stopped | AarSvc_51453 | Agent Activation Runtime_51453 | AudioEndpointBuilder |
| Stopped | AarSvc | Agent Activation Runtime | AudioEndpointBuilder |
| Running | Audiosrv | Windows Audio | AudioEndpointBuilder |

What the query returns: Status, Name, DisplayName

What I need the query to return: Status, Name, DisplayName, Parent Name

I've tried $row, making a new array by piping through to Select-Object within my Script block, and wrapping $_ in [ $_ ], " $_ ", or "[$_]".

```
| Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName,  [PSCustomObject]@{Name="Parent Name";Expression={$_.name}}
```

I'm using Powershell 5.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "Parent name", you mean that you want the services that the current service depends upon to be running, then you would do it the following way.

`ServicesDependedOn` is an array, so it might output more than one result.

```
Get-Service -DependentServices | Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName,  @{Name="Parent Name";Expression={$_.ServicesDependedOn}} | Sort Name
```

You were nearly there, but the calculated property take a hashtable, not a PSCustomObject. Also, if you use `$_.Name` as the expression, you will just repeat the `Name` value you already selected so you need to target the expression you want as a value instead.

**References**

[ServiceController class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

[About Calculated properties (PS 5.1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-5.1)